# Get the object that raises the listener

Tags: java, android, listener

I put this listener on several swipelistview

```
BaseSwipeListViewListener myBaseSwipeListViewListener = new BaseSwipeListViewListener() {
            @Override
            public void onOpened(int position, boolean toRight) {
            //Here I need the calling swipelistview
            }
}
```

with

```
swipelistview0.setSwipeListViewListener(myBaseSwipeListViewListener);
swipelistview1.setSwipeListViewListener(myBaseSwipeListViewListener);
swipelistview2.setSwipeListViewListener(myBaseSwipeListViewListener); //and so on
```

How could I get the calling swipelistview ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I am not sure if I got you but what about just adding another parameter to your listener callback method? Like this:

```
BaseSwipeListViewListener myBaseSwipeListViewListener = new BaseSwipeListViewListener(){
    @Override
    public void onOpened(int position, boolean toRight, SwipeListView swipeListView) {
        //Here you now have your calling swipelistview
    } 
}
```

In your BaseSwipeListViewListener now just add the third parameter by returning itself (this).

**Update: I did not know that it is a library. This is not what I would do but if you don't want to edit the source just do the following:**

```
BaseSwipeListViewListener myBaseSwipeListViewListener0 = new BaseSwipeListViewListener() {
    @Override
    public void onOpened(int position, boolean toRight) {
        onOpenedAdvanced(position, toRight, swipelistview0);
    } 
}

BaseSwipeListViewListener myBaseSwipeListViewListener1 = new BaseSwipeListViewListener() {
    @Override
    public void onOpened(int position, boolean toRight) {
        onOpenedAdvanced(position, toRight, swipelistview1);
    } 
}

BaseSwipeListViewListener myBaseSwipeListViewListener2 = new BaseSwipeListViewListener() {
    @Override
    public void onOpened(int position, boolean toRight) {
        onOpenedAdvanced(position, toRight, swipelistview0);
    } 
}

public void onOpenedAdvanced(int position, boolean toRight, SwipeListView swipeListView){
    //Here you now have your calling swipelistview
}

swipelistview0.setSwipeListViewListener(myBaseSwipeListViewListener0);
swipelistview1.setSwipeListViewListener(myBaseSwipeListViewListener1);
swipelistview2.setSwipeListViewListener(myBaseSwipeListViewListener2);
```

Comment: Ok for this one, but for public void onClickFrontView(int position,SwipeListView swipeListView) it goes marked as unused

Comment: Okay I thought this is your own class. But I guess that is wrong? Are you using -> https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview?

Comment: @ Julian Liebl Yes :-)

Comment: That's what I did first, but I thought there was a shorter way :-). Thanks for help

Comment: The shorter and better way is to fork the project (github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview) and adjust the source for your needs. You could also use reflection but this is most of the times a sign of bad design.